# How to make a notification sent to certain window 10 PC

Tags: java, push-notification, system-tray

I had done the system tray to send the notification to the PC and run the java program.
How can I modify it to be able to send to certain PC using an IP address?

Below is the code that I had done.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType;

    public class MemoSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            MemoSample td = new MemoSample();
            td.displayTray();
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.err.println("System tray not supported!");
        }
    }

    public void displayTray() throws AWTException {
        //Obtain only one instance of the SystemTray object
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        //Get image
    Image trayIconImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("icon.png");
    int trayIconWidth = new TrayIcon(trayIconImage).getSize().width;
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(trayIconImage.getScaledInstance(trayIconWidth, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    //Let the system resizes the image if needed
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

    trayIcon.setToolTip("Notification from system");
    tray.add(trayIcon);
    trayIcon.displayMessage("You Have a pending job", "Notification from system" ,MessageType.INFO);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this would be a bit complicated...

You can accomplish this by setting up a server with the java ServerSocket. You can then connect to that server with Sockets and send and recieve messges. Then you can show push notifications when receiving specific commands.

You could also set up a server on every device that should be able to recieve notifications which would make a single always running server obsolete. But I would not recommend doing it that way.

You can learn something about such network communication in Java on for example this [Page](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets).